# Issue in getting the pySpark dataframe Column data into a List Variable

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a input dataframe: df_meta

```
comment|inp_col|inp_val|
11     |a      |1      |
12     |a      |2      |
13     |a      |3      |
14     |a      |4      |
15     |b      |5      |
16     |b      |6      |
17     |c      |b      |
17     |c      |7      |
```

Here, I want to get the list of values from **inp_val** column based on the **inp_col** value passed.

**Scenario 1:**
To the list of values where inp_col == 'a'

```
df_selected = df_meta.select(df_meta.inp_val).where(df_meta.inp_col == 'a')
a_list = [row['inp_col'] for row in df_selected.collect()]
Output: a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**Scenario 2:**
To the list of values where inp_col == 'b'

```
df_selected = df_meta.select(df_meta.inp_val).where(df_meta.inp_col == 'b')
b_list = [row['inp_col'] for row in df_selected.collect()]
Output: b_list = [5, 6]
```

**Scenario 3:**
To the list of values where inp_col == 'c'

```
df_selected = df_meta.select(df_meta.inp_val).where(df_meta.inp_col == 'c')
c_list = [row['inp_col'] for row in df_selected.collect()]
Output: c_list = [b, 7]
```

**But, I want the c_list output as c_list = [5, 6, 7]**

How to replace the variable b with its list value. So my output should be as :
**c_list = [5, 6, 7]** instead **c_list = [b, 7]**

**Can we add some special charector to the variables in inp_val to undertand it has some meaning and it has ro replace with its value. Like below:**

```
comment|inp_col|inp_val |
17     |c      |#b      |
17     |c      |7       |
```

Comment: You can modify a list like this.                                    Names = ['Jon', 'Bill', 'Maria', 'Jenny', 'Jack']

#modify
Names[2] = 'Mona'

Comment: Thank you. But, we should handle dynamically.

Comment: You can loop through the list and find the position of b and store in a temp veritable..in next line you can update the position

Comment: Dynamically, I don't know the value as 'b' here i have given an example. But, we have to write the code insuch a way that if it found b then it should also replace the b list values too.